# Преобразовать массив reduce'ом

Tags: javascript

Как преобразовать массив так, чтобы сложить все не пустые 'arr' и запушить в них соответствующий объект "user" ?

```js
//исходный массив
let test = [{
    id: 1,
    user: {
      user_id: 1
    },
    array: [{
        arr: 1.1,
      },
      {
        arr: 1.2,
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    user: {
      user_id: 2
    },
    array: [{
      arr: 2.1,
    }, ]
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    user: {
      user_id: 3
    },
    array: []
  }
]

//результат преобразования
let result = [{
    arr: 1.1,
    user: {
      user_id: 1
    },
  },
  {
    arr: 1.2,
    user: {
      user_id: 1
    },
  },
  {
    arr: 2.1,
    user: {
      user_id: 2
    },
  },
]
```

Получилось наваять вот такое:

```js
let res = []
test.reduce((acc, cur, index) => {
  if (cur.array.length) {
    acc[cur.user.user_id] = acc[cur.user.user_id] || {
      array: cur.array,
    };

    let a = cur.array.map(item => {
      let b = item
      b.user = cur.user
      return bbb
    })
    res.push(a)

    return acc;
  }
}, {})
```

Как можно упростить?

Comment: Что куда сложить нужно ? есть пример что должно получить? result  - это так как должно быть?

Comment: да result , это то как должно выглядеть

Comment: Тут reduce не очень в тему...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможно, так:

```js
var data = [{
  id: 1,
  user: { user_id: 1 },
  array: [{ arr: 1.1 }, { arr: 1.2 }]
}, {
  id: 2,
  user: { user_id: 2 },
  array: [{ arr: 2.1 }]
}, {
  id: 3,
  user: { user_id: 3 },
  array: []
}]

console.log(data.flatMap(({ user, array }) => array.map(({ arr }) => ({ arr, user }))))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100vh }
```

Или так:

```js
var data = [{
  id: 1,
  user: { user_id: 1 },
  array: [{ arr: 1.1 }, { arr: 1.2 }]
}, {
  id: 2,
  user: { user_id: 2 },
  array: [{ arr: 2.1 }]
}, {
  id: 3,
  user: { user_id: 3 },
  array: []
}]

console.log(data.flatMap(({ user, array }) => array.map(({ arr }) => ({ arr, user: { ...user } }))))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100vh }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//Исходные данные
let test = [...];

// Вспомогательный ассоциативный массив
const m = new Map();
// Через reduce
test.reduce( (acc, cur, index) => {
    cur.array.forEach( a => {
        if ( !m.has(a.arr) ) {
            m.set(a.arr, {
              arr: a.arr,
              user: cur.user
            });
        }        
    });
    return cur;
}, test[0]);

// Или через forEach
test.forEach(  t => {
    t.array.forEach( a => {
        // Если в массиве нет такого ключа, то добавляем
        if ( !m.has(a.arr) ) {
            // Добавляем ключ-значение
            m.set(a.arr, {
               arr: a.arr,
               user: t.user
            });
        }
    });
});

// Результат в обоих случаях одинаковый
const result = Array.from(m.values());
console.log(result);

/* 
[ { arr: 1.1, user: { user_id: 1 } },
  { arr: 1.2, user: { user_id: 1 } },
  { arr: 2.1, user: { user_id: 2 } } ]
*/
```